# SpriteKit SKSpriteNode moves

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have some textures...

```
placeForJump = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "placeForJump")
placeForJump.position = CGPoint(x: 512.346, y: 98.88)
placeForJump.size = CGSize(width: 166.407, height: 197.762)
placeForJump.zPosition = 2
self.addChild(placeForJump)
```

and character...

```
player = SKSPriteNode(imageNamed: "character")
player.position...
player.size...
player.zPozition = 3
self.addChild(player)
```

When I touch the texture where I can jump, I want my character to jump on this place, but I don't know how to do that.

When I touch the texture with placeForJump - my character jump on it.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by detecting a touch on the place to jump and then when the user touches it you can run an action to move the character there.

To detect if the user touches the place to jump you can add this code to the touchesBegan or touchesEnded functions:

```
for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if placeForJump.containsPoint(location) {
             print("It was touched")
        }
}
```

Then to run an action to the place you will want to use an SKAction like this:

```
player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(placeForJump.position, duration: speed)
```

This will move the player node to the placeForJump in the shortes possible way so if you want it to go higher and then to the place you can do it like this:

```
let highPoint = CGPoint(x: player.position.x + 50, y: player.position.y + 100)

let moveUp = SKAction.moveTo(highPoint, duration: speed)
let moveDown = SKAction.moveTo(placeForJump.position, duration: speed)
player.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveUp, moveDown])
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: Hello! Your answer was really helpful. Thank you very much.
And special thanks for this part of code:
let highPoint = CGPoint(x: player.position.x + 50, y: player.position.y + 100)

let moveUp = SKAction.moveTo(highPoint, duration: speed)
let moveDown = SKAction.moveTo(placeForJump.position, duration: speed)
player.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveUp, moveDown])